# How can I exit/close the Android Emulator from within a Script

Tags: android, bash, process, emulation

I've made a bash script that runs on an VM using Ubuntu that starts like this:

```
nohup emulator @2.1 -snapshot 1 -no-snapshot-save & 
echo ----------- Waiting for Device
adb wait-for-device
```

I then do some stuff and want to close/exit the emulator abandoning the changed state after the script is done. My problem is, that I don't know how to exit the emulator - clean. 
I thought about grabbing the emulators process ID and kill -9 it, but is there a 'nicer' way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know adb, there is no way to stop the emulator gracefully. The docs say pressing Ctrl+C stops the emulator, therefore a kill -15 should work (and is 'nicer' than a kill -9).

```
nohup emulator
EMULATOR_PID=$!

#actions

kill -15 $EMULATOR_PID
```

Comment: I also just came up with an ungraceful but working: **kill -9 `ps ax | grep -m 1 "emulator-arm" | awk '{ print $1 }'`**             The -m 1 is necessary because I initialize another process with "emulator-arm" in its name because of the grep. I always got the two PIDs when I echoed the line above. The -m 1 stops after the first line found.

Comment: The above comment not works for me, since my process is named "emulator64-arm". With ps ax | grep -m 2  "emulator64-arm" | awk '{ print $1 }' I see the 1st entry is the grep and the 2nd is the one to be killed. :-( So I manually do my ps and then kill the emulator.